# OnCreateOptionsmenu called once in viewpager with tablayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-optionsmenu, oncreateoptionsmenu

I have a rare problem. I have an activity that has tabs populated dynamically (up to 20 tabs). Each fragment has an implementation of `OnCreateOptionsMenu` and a menu which contains a bookmark icon that changes color when pressed. There is a class variable `menu` of type `Menu` which is set when fragment's `OnCreateOptionsMenu` is called. This is to enable me set the bookmark menu item outside the `onCreateOptionsMenu`(This is also done dynamically).

**Problem**:
When the parent activity have only a single tab(One fragment instance), this implementation works fine. However with more than one tab, the app crashes with the error: 
`Attempt to invoke interface method android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)`

**What I think**: I think the problem is that the `OnCreateOptionsMenu` is called once i.e Class variable: `menu` is set only once for the first tab (fragment) hence when other tabs are added, `menu` is `null`

**Some codes**: 
Fragment

```
Menu menu;
...
...
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 setMenuBookmark(ques_obj);
}

private void setMenuBookmark(QuestionAnswerList ques_obj){
        MenuItem menuBookmark = this.menu.findItem(R.id.action_bookmark);

        if (ques_obj.getIs_bookmarked().equals("1")) {
            menuBookmark.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_white_24dp);
        } else {
            menuBookmark.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_border_white_24dp);
        }
    }

...
...

@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.cbt_fragment_menu, menu);
        this.menu = menu;

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

P.S setHasOptionsMenu() is set to true in Fragment's OnCreate

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()
            }
         }, 500 );

    }



    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.cbt_fragment_menu, menu);

         MenuItem menuBookmark = menu.findItem(R.id.action_bookmark)

         if (ques_obj.getIs_bookmarked().equals("1")) {
            menuBookmark.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_white_24dp);
         } else {
            menuBookmark.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_border_white_24dp);
         }

         return true;
    }
```

Comment: Where is invalidateOptionsMenu() coming from? Android studio cannot resolve it

Comment: Tried this but got null exception on ques_obj